# How to generate XML using a non-recursive algorithm (trouble with the closing tag part)

Tags: javascript, xml, algorithm, recursion

It's very easy to generate XML using recursion.

```
function xml(node) {
  var str = []
  str.push('<' + node.tag + '>')
  node.children.forEach(function(child){
    str.push(xml(child))
  })
  return str.join('')
}
```

But I am having a hard time trying to figure out how to do this same thing without recursion.

It is easy to write a non-recursive loop:

```
function loopWithoutRecursion(node, fn) {
  var stack = [node]
  while (stack.length) {
    var node = stack.pop()
    fn(node)
    if (node.children) {
      node.children.forEach(function(child){
        stack.push(child)
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Using that like:

```
loopWithoutRecursion(start, function(node){
  // ...
})
```

But the tricky part is *how to handle the closing tags*:

```
var str = []
loopWithoutRecursion(node, function(node){
  str.push('<' + node.tag + '>')
  // ... I'm stuck
})
```

I've tried this approach that didn't work:

```
var openStr = []
var closeStr = []
loopWithoutRecursion(node, function(node){
  openStr.push('<' + node.tag + '>')
  closeStr.push('</' + node.tag + '>')
})

var str = []
openStr.forEach(function(openTag, i){
  var closeTag = closeStr[i]
  str.push(openTag + closeTag)
})
```

But that is the same as just doing this:

```
var str = []
loopWithoutRecursion(node, function(node){
  str.push('<' + node.tag + '>')
  str.push('</' + node.tag + '>')
})
```

So I'm wondering if there is a straightforward solution to this problem or if it will take jumping through a lot of hoops (creating a lot of intermediate structures). I feel like computer science probably has this one solved easily already, but I don't know where to begin.

Comment: Why would you want a non-recursive solution for a problem that is so naturally recursive in its nature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a fairly straightforward solution. Every single time you make a recursive call, it is actually being pushed to the so called **call stack** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack). The basic thing about the call stack is that it (roughly) contains the parameters with which the functions were called, and a **return pointer** - the place in the code that should be executed after the function is finished. I really recommend reading more about how functions are called under the hood, that will clear out a lot.

In general, your stack needs to contain both the **parameter** and the **thing to do**.

### Solution

Your recursive function in simplified pseudocode:

```
func xml(node):
    print node.open_tag
    for child in node.children:
        xml(child)
    print node.close_tag
```

In this case, the parameter part is easy - it is simply the `node`. However, the thing to do can vary.

- If you have just started processing a tag, you should print the opening, and start handling the children.
- If you are returning to the parent from a child, you should close the tag.

This is exactly what I'm doing here:

```
function loopWithoutRecursion(node, open, close) {
  var stack = [[node, 'open']]
  while (stack.length) {
    var stack_frame = stack.pop()
    var node = stack_frame[0]
    var mode = stack_frame[1]

    if (mode == 'open') {
      open(node)

      stack.push([node, 'close'])

      if (node.children) {
          node.children.reverse().forEach(function(child){
            stack.push([child, 'open'])
          })
      }
    } else {
      close(node)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You might find this stack exchange thread interesting https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/195385/understanding-stack-frame-of-function-call-in-c-c

Comment: Not sure what stack.top is supposed to do, either stack.shift() or stack.pop()

Comment: Fixed. Should be `pop()`. Remains of an old idea.

Comment: @LancePollard fixed some mistakes, and tested the function. Let me know if you have any issues!

Comment: It reverses the order of the children, maybe just iterating backwards, hmm

Comment: @LancePollard Stacks naturally reverse the order, added reversing the children.

Comment: now struggling with this version https://gist.github.com/lancejpollard/490955f1a225b1ea348ad93d197ea50a